# Symfony2 russian translation: input is not proper UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, xliff

I'm facing a problem with my symfony2 project. I need translation files for russian language. English, German and Hungarian works like a charm, but I have problems with the russian version. The schemes are copy-pasted from the other language files, only the translated string differs. I use UTF-8 encoding without BOM in every .xliff files of mine. The scheme is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>acquisition_request_form.title</source>
                <target>Запрос предложения</target>
            </trans-unit>...
```

So when I try to check the russian version, it gives me an exception:

```
RuntimeException: [ERROR 522] Validation failed: no DTD found ! (in n/a -
line 2, column 21) [ERROR 9] Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! 
Bytes: 0xD1 0xF2 0xE0 0xF0 (in n/a - line 7, column 25) (uncaught exception) 
at /srv/bav/buildNumber221-appVersion940-coreVersion4064/bav-common/vendor
/Symfony/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader
/XliffFileLoader.php line 70
```

I know what the error message means but don't know why it gives me this error, when every single file on the server is utf-8 encoded. I checked it. Five times. So, I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get the `[ERROR 522]` also for the other languages? If you open your Russian xliff file in a hex editor, does it contain that byte sequence `d1 f2 e0 f0`? If you add some ASCII characters before the cyrillc characters does the column offset for `[ERROR 9]` move?